# SCRIPT5009: 'submit' is undefined xxxx.asp, line 43 character 1

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I am getting the above error in the console window. The page has a text box and the button. After entering the value(Reg code) in the text box, the value is passed to DB to fetch information about the Reg code. But when clicking the button nothing happens and in console I can see the above error. I am using IE9
This is **working fine in IE9 Compatibility view**. The code from Developer tool is shown below. Please advise me how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance !

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Vehicle Information List</title>
<link REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="/msclassicdealer/bin/include/intranet.css">
</head>

<form NAME="PartsVehicleInfo" ACTION="PartsVehicleInfo.asp" METHOD="post">

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function ClickImage(n){
        var objSrc = window.event.srcElement.style;
        objSrc.posTop = n;
        objSrc.posLeft = n; 
    }
</script>

<body BACKGROUND="/msclassicdealer/bin/images/background.gif" BGCOLOR="#ffffff">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="75" height="22">&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="middle" align="center" class="titleback"><p class="heading">Vehicle Information</p></td>
        <td width="75">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>   

</table>

<table align="center" border="0" cellPadding="0" cellSpacing="0">
<tr>
    <td colspan=2>Please enter vehicle registration information</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan=2><br></td></tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right"><b>Registration (VRM)&nbsp;&nbsp;</b></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtReg" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>    
    <td colspan="2" align="center">
        <a onclick="submit()" style="cursor: pointer;"/>
        <img name="Search" alt="Search for vehicle" src="/msclassicdealer/bin/images/buttons/search.gif" border="0" style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;" onmousedown="ClickImage(2)" onmouseup="ClickImage(0)" width="30" height="30"/>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>


</body>
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML isn't well-formed (`<body>` inside `<form>`) but anyway...`submit()` **is not defined** (at least in code you provide). Give an ID to your form and submit with `document.yourFormId.submit()`. As alternative keep `<form>` with `name` only and use `GetElementsByName()` (or `document.forms[0]` list).

Answer (score 0):

That's all quite ... old school.

`<a onclick="submit()" ...`

You have no such function.

`<a onclick="document.forms['PartsVehicleInfo'].submit();" ...`